# Array printing same results from API call

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am building an app whereby you enter ingredients and you return a bunch of recipes based on your input. I'm making the calls to the API using alamofire and these seem to be successful. The problem I'm having is the 6 results in my test call are repeating 1 recipe 6 times rather than returning all the results in separate cells. This is the API call code:

```
import Alamofire

class RecipeAp: NSObject{

var concoctions = [RecipeDetails]()

func provideRecipeDetailsForName(name: String, completed:@escaping ([RecipeDetails]) -> Void) {
    let urlSearchString = URL_FULL + "onion" + "soup"
    Alamofire.request(urlSearchString).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
        let details = RecipeDetails()
        let result = response.result
        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            if let matches = dict["matches"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                for ingredient in matches {
                    if let name = ingredient["ingredients"] as? [String] {
                        details.ingredients = name
                        self.concoctions.append(details)

                    }
                }

                for recipeName in matches {
                    if let name = recipeName["recipeName"] as? String {
                        details.recipeTitle = name
                        print("the recipe name = \(name.debugDescription)")
                        self.concoctions.append(details)

                    }

                }

            }

            completed(self.concoctions)

        }



    })

}

}
```

**This is my model:**

```
  class RecipeDetails: NSObject {
   var recipeID: String?
   var recipeImageURL: String?
   var recipeTitle: String?
   var recipeSourceURL: String?
   var recipePublisher: String?
   var ingredients: [String]?
}
```

**This is my customCell setup**

```
   import UIKit

 class RecipeListCustomCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var recipeTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var recipeUrl: UILabel!

var recipe: RecipeDetails? {

    didSet {

        updateView()

    }

}

func updateView() {

    recipeTitle.text = recipe?.recipeTitle
    recipeUrl.text = recipe?.recipeSourceURL


   }

 }
```

**And finally this is my viewController**

```
 import UIKit

 class MainVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var recipe = RecipeAp()
var results = [RecipeDetails]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadRecipes()

}


     func loadRecipes() {

    recipe.provideRecipeDetailsForName(name: "onion" + "soup") { (response) in

        self.results = response
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

   }

 }

 extension MainVC: UITableViewDataSource {

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
 section: Int) -> Int {
    return results.count
}

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
  IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
    "RecipeListCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! RecipeListCustomCell
    let recipe = results[indexPath.row]
    cell.recipe = recipe

    return cell


   }

 }
```

Not sure how to display all the recipes separately in each cell. I have also attached some screen shots on what I am getting back from the API and the display in the simulator.

[image: simulator output]

[image: result back from Api]

Comment: can you do teamviewer or zoom session so i can help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create only one instance of `RecipeDetails` for each response. So, you add exactly the same reference into your `self.concoctions` repeatedly.

You may need to write something like this:

```
func provideRecipeDetailsForName(name: String, completed: @escaping ([RecipeDetails]) -> Void) {
    let urlSearchString = URL_FULL + "onion" + "soup"
    Alamofire.request(urlSearchString).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
        let result = response.result
        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            if let matches = dict["matches"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                for match in matches {
                    //### Create a new instance for each iteration.
                    let details = RecipeDetails()
                    if let ingredients = match["ingredients"] as? [String] {
                        details.ingredients = ingredients
                    }
                    if let recipeName = match["recipeName"] as? String {
                        details.recipeTitle = recipeName
                        print("the recipe name = \(recipeName.debugDescription)")
                    }
                    //### Add the instance once in the iteration
                    self.concoctions.append(details)
                }
            }

            completed(self.concoctions)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: ah ha of course, thanks for this thats solved the issue many thanks